# I'm looking for a list like this in the image for Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, listview, listbox, delphi-xe3

Anybody knows where to find or how to make a list like this one in Delphi XE3 ?
Or it's time to leave Delphi and use Visual studio ?

however this site  [list view control for .NET Windows Forms](http://www.componentowl.com/documentation/better-listview/data/chapter-multi-line.html) claims that this control can be used with .NET and I believe that Delphi support .Net but I didn't use .Net with Delphi before, Do u think it will work with Delphi .Net?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is a TreeView, not a ListView.  You can create that kind of display using an owner-drawn TreeView, or a third-party TreeView like [Virtual TreeView](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23%3avirtual-treeview-component&catid=14%3acontrols&Itemid=134).

Answer (score 0):

After a hard searching I found this code which is mimicking the List view to achieve that grouping type of list, and with the help of the Timagelist list, u can create ur own arrow like icons.

Thanks for [http://delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/delphi-list-view-groups-expand-collapse-items.htm)

```
unit Unit1;

interface


uses
  Contnrs,
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ImgList, ComCtrls;

type
  TGroupItem = class
  private
    fItems : TObjectList;
    fCaption: string;
    fListItem: TListItem;
    fExpanded: boolean;
    function GetItems: TObjectList;
  public
    constructor Create(const caption : string; const numberOfSubItems : integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Expand;
    procedure Collapse;

    property Expanded : boolean read fExpanded;
    property Caption : string read fCaption;
    property Items : TObjectList read GetItems;
    property ListItem : TListItem read fListItem write fListItem;
  end;

  TItem = class
  private
    fTitle: string;
    fValue: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const title, value : string);
    property Title: string read fTitle;
    property Value : string read fValue;
  end;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lvGroups: TListView;
    listViewImages: TImageList;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lvGroupsAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
      Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
      var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
    procedure lvGroupsDblClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure ClearListViewGroups;
    procedure FillListViewGroups;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.ClearListViewGroups;
var
  li : TListItem;
  qng : TGroupItem;
begin
  for li in lvGroups.Items do
  begin
    if TObject(li.Data) is TGroupItem then
    begin
      qng := TGroupItem(li.Data);
      FreeAndNil(qng);
    end;
  end;
  lvGroups.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.FillListViewGroups;

  procedure AddGroupItem(gi : TGroupItem);
  var
    li : TListItem;
  begin
    li := lvGroups.Items.Add;

    li.Caption := gi.Caption;
    li.ImageIndex := 1; //collapsed

    li.Data := gi;
    gi.ListItem := li; //link "back"
  end;
begin
  ClearListViewGroups;

  AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group A', 3));
  AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group B', 1));
  AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group C', 4));
  AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group D', 5));
 AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group D', 5));
  AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group D', 5));
   AddGroupItem(TGroupItem.Create('Group D', 5));

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FillListViewGroups;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClearListViewGroups;
end;

procedure TForm1.lvGroupsAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  //bold group items
  if TObject(item.Data) is TGroupItem then
  begin
    lvGroups.Canvas.Font.Style := lvGroups.Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  end;
end;

//handles TListView OnDblClick even
procedure TForm1.lvGroupsDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  hts : THitTests;
  gi : TGroupItem;
begin
  inherited;

  hts := lvGroups.GetHitTestInfoAt(lvGroups.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).X, lvGroups.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos).y);

  if (lvGroups.Selected <> nil) then
  begin
    if TObject(lvGroups.Selected.Data) is (TGroupItem) then
    begin
      gi := TGroupItem(lvGroups.Selected.Data);

      if NOT gi.Expanded then
        gi.Expand
      else
        gi.Collapse;
    end;
  end;
end;


{$region 'TGroupItem'}

procedure TGroupItem.Collapse;
var
  li : TListItem;
begin
  if NOT Expanded then Exit;

  ListItem.ImageIndex := 1;
  fExpanded := false;

  li := TListView(ListItem.ListView).Items[ListItem.Index + 1];
  while (li <> nil) AND (TObject(li.Data) is TItem) do
  begin
    TListView(ListItem.ListView).Items.Delete(li.Index);
    li := TListView(ListItem.ListView).Items[ListItem.Index + 1];
  end;
end;

constructor TGroupItem.Create(const caption: string; const numberOfSubItems : integer);
var
  cnt : integer;
begin
  fCaption := caption;

  for cnt := 1 to numberOfSubItems do
  begin
    Items.Add(TItem.Create(caption + ' item ' + IntToStr(cnt), IntToStr(cnt)));
  end;
end;

destructor TGroupItem.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(fItems);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGroupItem.Expand;
var
  cnt : integer;
  item : TItem;
begin
  if Expanded then Exit;

  ListItem.ImageIndex := 0;
  fExpanded := true;

  for cnt := 0 to -1 + Items.Count do
  begin
    item := TItem(Items[cnt]);
    with TListView(ListItem.ListView).Items.Insert(1 + cnt + ListItem.Index) do
    begin
      Caption := item.Title;
      SubItems.Add(item.Value);
      Data := item;
      ImageIndex := -1;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TGroupItem.GetItems: TObjectList;
begin
  if fItems = nil then fItems := TObjectList.Create(true);
  result := fItems;
end;
{$endregion}

{$region 'TItem' }

constructor TItem.Create(const title, value: string);
begin
  fTitle := title;
  fValue := value;
end;
{$endregion}

end.
```